# SwiftUI - Picker not working when inside a Form (iPad split view)

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

I'm using Xcode 11 GM

The hierarchy I have is:

List > Form (Picker)

This is the code for List:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{

        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: FormView())
            {
            Text("Item 1")
          }

        }
       .navigationBarTitle("List")

       }


    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the Form:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FormView: View {

    var body: some View {


        Form {
            Picker(selection: .constant(1), label: Text("Picker")) {
                Text("1").tag(1)
                Text("2").tag(2)

            }

           }
        .navigationBarTitle("Form")



    }
}

struct FormView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FormView()
    }
}
```

The problem is:

When I build on iPad split view, tap to select works as expected:

[image]

But, when inside tags I cannot select them, nor it will go back to form view:
[image]

On iPhone, it works fine...

Is this a known bug?

Cheers to all

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, it seems that the picker cells expect the user to tap on the Text elements themselves.

I don't know why. I think it's weird, too, and probably a bug. Not sure Apple knows about it yet. I sure haven't filed a radar.

To confirm this, try testing with longer text in the picker items.

What I normally do is implement a simple picker myself (not that hard, just a `List` and some items) and implement the items as `Button`s. (If it changes the color on me, I change it back using `.foregroundColor(.primary)`). What's nice about this is that a `Button` inside a `Form` or a `List` renders as the table view cell we're used to, with the same highlighting interaction we all know and love!